# Raspbmc on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am running [raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/) on a Raspberry Pi (Model B). I am wondering if:

- there are any modifications or settings I can change to make the menu faster? Navigation is very slow on this device.
- there is a way for me to search for a title without having to scroll through my entire list of media.
- do not separate directories from files. At the moment if I list all movies, it will render a list of all the directories I have (in alphabetical order) followed by a second list of files. I would like this to be all put in a single alphabetised order.

Comment: Not sure how slow "very slow" is, but you might consider using a faster SD card if you're currently using a slow-ish one.

Comment: If you put all your movies in a single folder this will fix that?  You can use the number keys to get through the list quickly.  Ie hitting 5 will take you to the titles beginning with J,K and L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to speed up your XBMC.

- Overclocking
- Use leight weight skin ([Quartz](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on:Quartz) for example)
- use NFS instead SMB
- ... etc

Yes. Use the [Global Search](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on:Global_Search) Addon.

Use the Movie/Music/TV Show library instead of the video list.